# Hadoop / MapReduce - Optimizing "Top N" Word Count MapReduce Job

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working on something similar to the canonical MapReduce example - the word count, but with a twist in that I'm looking to only get the **Top N** results.

Let's say I have a very large set of text data in HDFS.  There are plenty of examples that show how to build a Hadoop MapReduce job that will provide you with a word count for every word in that text.  For example, if my corpus is:

> "This is a test of test data and a good one to test this"

The result set from the standard MapReduce word count job would be:

> test:3, a:2, this:2, is: 1, etc..

But what if I **ONLY** want to get the Top 3 words that were used in my entire set of data?

I can still run the exact same standard MapReduce word-count job, and then just take the Top 3 results once it is ready and is spitting out the count for EVERY word, but that seems a little inefficient, because a lot of data needs to be moved around during the shuffle phase.

What I'm thinking is that, if this sample is large enough, and the data is well randomly and well distributed in HDFS, that each Mapper does not need to send ALL of its word counts to the Reducers, but rather, only some of the top data.  So if one mapper has this:

> a:8234, the: 5422, man: 4352, ......  *many more words* ...  , rareword: 1, weirdword: 1, etc.

Then what I'd like to do is only send the Top 100 or so words from each Mapper to the Reducer phase - since there is very little chance that "rareword" will suddenly end up in the Top 3 when all is said and done.  This seems like it would save on bandwidth and also on Reducer processing time.

Can this be done in the Combiner phase?  Is this sort of optimization prior to the shuffle phase commonly done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very good question, because you have hit the inefficiency of Hadoop's word count example.

The tricks to optimize your problem are the following:

Do a `HashMap` based grouping in your local map stage, you can also use a combiner for that. This can look like this, I'm using the `HashMultiSet` of Guava, which faciliates a nice counting mechanism.

```
    public static class WordFrequencyMapper extends
      Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

    private final HashMultiset<String> wordCountSet = HashMultiset.create();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      String[] tokens = value.toString().split("\\s+");
      for (String token : tokens) {
        wordCountSet.add(token);
      }
    }
```

And you emit the result in your cleanup stage:

```
@Override
protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
    InterruptedException {
  Text key = new Text();
  LongWritable value = new LongWritable();
  for (Entry<String> entry : wordCountSet.entrySet()) {
    key.set(entry.getElement());
    value.set(entry.getCount());
    context.write(key, value);
  }
}
```

So you have grouped the words in a local block of work, thus reducing network usage by using a bit of RAM. You can also do the same with a `Combiner`, but it is sorting to group-  so this would be slower (especially for strings!) than using a `HashMultiset`.

To just get the Top N, you will only have to write the Top N in that local `HashMultiset` to the output collector and aggregate the results in your normal way on the reduce side. 
This saves you a lot of network bandwidth as well, the only drawback is that you need to sort the word-count tuples in your cleanup method.

A part of the code might look like this:

```
  Set<String> elementSet = wordCountSet.elementSet();
  String[] array = elementSet.toArray(new String[elementSet.size()]);
  Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
      // sort descending
      return Long.compare(wordCountSet.count(o2), wordCountSet.count(o1));
    }

  });
  Text key = new Text();
  LongWritable value = new LongWritable();
  // just emit the first n records
  for(int i = 0; i < N, i++){
    key.set(array[i]);
    value.set(wordCountSet.count(array[i]));
    context.write(key, value);
  }
```

Hope you get the gist of doing as much of the word locally and then just aggregate the top N of the top N's ;)

Comment: Is it considered a good practice to store the set of output data for a mapper in RAM (as you do here by storing it all in a HashMultiset), rather than having each 'map' call be independent of all others?

Comment: Yes it is, in order to save network bandwidth you can sacrifice memory.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting Thomas

> To just get the Top N, you will only have to write the Top N in that
>   local HashMultiset to the output collector and aggregate the results
>   in your normal way on the reduce side. This saves you a lot of network
>   bandwidth as well, the only drawback is that you need to sort the
>   word-count tuples in your cleanup method.

If you write only top N in the local HashMultiset then there is a possibility that you are going to miss the count of an element that, If passed from this local HashMultiset, could become one of the overall top 10 elements.

For example consider following format as three maps as MapName: elementName,elemenntcount:

Map A : Ele1,4 : Ele2,5 : Ele3,5 : Ele4,2

Map B : Ele1,1 : Ele5,7 : Ele6, 3 : Ele7,6

Map C : Ele5,4 : Ele8,3 : Ele1,1 : Ele9,3

Now If we considered the top 3 of each mappers we will Miss the element "Ele1" whose total count should have been 6 but since we are calculating each mapper's top 3 we see "Ele1"'s total count as 4.

I hope that makes sense. Please let me know what you think about it.